# Knockout Subscribe to any change in observable complex object

Tags: knockout.js

I have a viewmodel which contains an observable, which is initialized with an object. 
this object itself contains observables.

my goal is to be notified whenever that object changes (or: when any observable in that object changes)

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/infantrash/xcajt4qn/)

**complex object**:

```
var ns = ns || {};

ns.ComplexObj = function (item) {
    var self = this;

    if (!item) {
        item = {};
    }

    self.id = item.Id || '';
    self.company = ko.observable(item.Company || '');
    self.email = ko.observable(item.Email || '');

    self.company.subscribe(function () {
       console.log('debug: company changed');
    });

    return self;
};
```

**viewmodel**

```
ns.mainvm = function () {
   var simpleObject = ko.observable('i am pretty simple');

   simpleObject.subscribe(function (newValue) {
       document.getElementById('simpleSubscribtionFeedback').innerText = newValue;
   });

   var complexObject = ko.observable(ns.ComplexObj());
   complexObject.subscribe(function (newValue) {
       // i would like to react to any change in complex object
       document.getElementById('complexSubscribtionFeedback').innerText = 'i dont get executed :(';
   });

   return {
       simpleObject: simpleObject,
       complexObject: complexObject
   };
};
```

**binding**

```
var container = document.getElementById('wrapper');
if (container) {
   ko.applyBindings(ns.mainvm, container);
} else {
   console.warn("container for binding ko not found");
}
```

is there any possiblity to react on changes on a complex object? any help is appreciated.

i already tried the dirtyFlag solutions (link in the comments), from rpniemeyer. the problem with a dirty flag on the complex object is, that when it switches to "true" and i'm hooking into the subscription of that flag, thats only ok for the first time. to react to further changes, i would need to set the dirtyFlag to false again (after doing my stuff in the subscription). which would lead into a subscription loop.

Comment: [This post](https://roysvork.wordpress.com/2014/01/12/tracking-changes-to-complex-viewmodels-with-knockout-js/) might get you started.

Comment: This plugin seems to be doing exactly what you ned: https://github.com/ZiadJ/knockoutjs-reactor

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use the following trick:

```
ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.toJSON(complexObject);
}).subscribe(function() {
    // called whenever any of the properties of complexObject changes
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/xcajt4qn/3/

The reason why this works is `ko.toJSON` will recursively read all the properties in the object, therefore making the computed depend on all the properties.

Comment: Note that this will also be called whenever any of the object's *non*-observable properties change, which may not be desired.

Comment: @tloflin how so? there wouldn't be any change tracking on those properties

Comment: Tip : Put a console.log in the subscribe to check it isn't being called too many times. You can use a rate limiting observable to avoid too many events which is especially useful if the fields are text inputs. Add `extend({ rateLimit: 500 })` before the `subscribe` function for that case. I believe `rateLimit: 0` or `extend({ deferred: true });` may be useful if you find you are getting multiple events raised for each change.

Comment: Is there a simple way to identify which property raised the change event?

Comment: Super clever - thank you for this!