# Observing all property changes within an observable

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I'm using KnockoutJS 3.4.

My view model (TypeScript) looks like this:

```
export class ItemsViewModel {
    public currentItem: KnockoutObservable<ItemViewModel>;
    public items: KnockoutObservableArray<KnockoutObservable<ItemViewModel>>;
    /* snip */
}
```

`ItemViewModel` contains a bunch of observable properties. These include `Id`, `Name` and `Description`.

I want to be able to subscribe to changes that happen within `currentItem`. Using `currentItem.subscribe` watches to changes of the `currentItem` observable value, not properties within the current item. I've seen the other question that was suggested as a duplicate, but that simply tracks changes to the whole object - I want to know when a specific property changes on that object.

How can I do this, in the most efficient manner possible?

**Edit** I've read the comments and linked question. It doesn't identify the changed property. I've updated this question to reflect that.

Comment: If by efficient you mean in terms of developer time then you can created a computed property that calls ko.toJS on your view-model. That will create a dependency to every observable within the view-model, and then you can subscribe to that property.

Comment: just for the sake of completeness, with `ko.toJS` you could also track changes only to some parts of your viewmodel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Knockout Subscribe to any change in observable complex object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27018684/knockout-subscribe-to-any-change-in-observable-complex-object)

Comment: regarding the possible duplicate question, if this question is about efficiency / speed i would notice here that ko.toJS is more performant than ko.toJSON

Comment: If the recursive part of `ko.toJS` is a performace drain, you could replace it with a loop that only calls `ko.unwrap` on each of the VMs properties. Additionally, I'd suggest making the computed a [deferred](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/deferred-updates.html) one so you can batch several property changes in to one recompution.

Comment: `KnockoutObservableArray<KnockoutObservable<ItemViewModel>>` why would you store `observables` in an `observableArray`? I'd suggest against that.

Comment: @user3297291: as i am truly interested in this topic, could you please elaborate? Are you aware of a method to replace the recursive viewmodel traversal with a (faster) loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to identify which property was modified you'll need a less generic solution. You can do this by attaching an extender to each property that needs to be tracked. I would have the extender accept a view-model level subscribable to notify, and the name of the property being extended. (sadly JavaScript doesn't have reflection to make that part code-able)

```
ko.extenders.trackChange = function (target, options) {
    target.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        if (ko.isSubscribable(options.notifier)) options.notifier.notifySubscribers(options.propertyName);
    });
    return target;
};
```

Then in your view-model add the subscribable and subscription.

```
self.propertyChanged = new ko.subscribable();
self.propertyChanged.subscribe(function(propertyName){
  console.log(propertyName + " was updated");
});
```

And finally add the extender to your properties.

```
self.property1 = ko.observable(0).extend({trackChange: { propertyName: 'property1', notifier: self.propertyChanged }});
self.property2 = ko.observable(0).extend({trackChange: { propertyName: 'property2', notifier: self.propertyChanged }});
self.property3 = ko.observable(0).extend({trackChange: { propertyName: 'property3', notifier: self.propertyChanged }});
```

If you want it on every single property you could automate attaching the extender with a loop on the view-model:

```
self.property1 = ko.observable();
self.property2 = ko.observable();
self.property3 = ko.observable();

for (key in self) {
    if (self.hasOwnProperty(key) && ko.isObservable(self[key])) {
        self[key].extend({trackChange: { propertyName: key, notifier: self.propertyChanged }})
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, this worked and did exactly what I wanted - thanks a lot.