# Is there a way to subscribe to a change in a observable object in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Im fairly new to knockout and we have a an observable object like this

`this.deeplinkPopupModule = ko.observable({ view: [], viewModel: null });`

I want to trigger a function whenever view or viewModel is changed or updated.

I have tried doing this, but this doesn't work, I have tried some other methods as well but those don't get triggered.

```
  this.deeplinkPopupModule.subscribe(function(newVal){
           
     console.log("inside module subscribe");

     if(this.deeplinkPopupModule.view.length==0) 
         this. addNewOpened(false);
           
  });
```

I cant use any plugins and I have also tried **sroes** answer here [Knockout Subscribe to any change in observable complex object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27018684/knockout-subscribe-to-any-change-in-observable-complex-object), but it was never triggerred
Please let me know if I should include any more information on this and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue you are having is that the properties on the deeplinkPopupModule are not knockout observables.  with out those, @sroes answer will not work.  Here is working example.

```js
function ViewModel () {
  var self = this;
  self.deeplinkPopupModule = ko.observable({
    view: ko.observableArray([]),
    viewModel: ko.observable(null)
  });

  ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.toJSON(self.deeplinkPopupModule);
  }).subscribe(function(newvalue) {
    console.log("inside module subscribe" + newvalue);

    if (self.deeplinkPopupModule().view().length == 0) {
      self.addNewOpened(false);
    }
  });
  self.addNewOpened = ko.observable(false);
  self.viewName = ko.observable();
  self.addView = function(){
    self.deeplinkPopupModule().view.push(self.viewName());
  }
  
}
var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="with: deeplinkPopupModule">
  <ul data-bind="foreach: view ">
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<input type="text" data-bind="value: viewName" />
<button data-bind="click: addView" >Add view</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

this.deeplinkPopupModule.subscribe(function(newVal){

```
 console.log("inside module subscribe");

 if(this.deeplinkPopupModule.view.length==0) 
     this. addNewOpened(false);
```

});